CryptoSwift.modulemap' not found in Xcode 15.3
/Users/mac3026/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/timeflyz-ckhdsrylzuzohaagbqtbcgtjhuja/Build/Intermediates.noindex/timeflyz.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/timeflyz.build/DerivedSources/timeflyz_vers.c module map file '/Users/mac3026/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/timeflyz-ckhdsrylzuzohaagbqtbcgtjhuja/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CryptoSwift/CryptoSwift.modulemap' not found
It happens when I create a build in xcode.
I have tried to install the ios 16.4 and 17.3 but it not get any solution.

Have you found solution for this?
